# Can I ask how to identify if a pencil is genuine brand or fake/counterfeit?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I want to know how I can identify whether or not the pencils I've bought or about to buy are genuine or fake/counterfeit.

I recently came to know that Faber-Castell fake/counterfeit products do exist and they have been reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this has an immediate effect on your projects (quality and longevity of pigment, and potentially other, unforeseen properties), I think this is certainly on-topic.

Do note that in order for such a question to be viable you have to be able to proof that you're dealing with counterfeits. In other words: such a question needs to be answerable by users who don't have physical access to the counterfeits.

Potential answers can then include asking the OP to perform specific tests that show differences between the two products, or check for certain consistencies.